# Как исправить ошибку: Failed to execute 'appendChild' on 'Node'

Tags: javascript, циклы, объекты

```
this.field = [];
let num = 0;
for (let i = 0; i < sizeX; i++) {
    this.field[i] = [];
    for (let k = 0; k < sizeY; k++) {
        if (k%2!==0) {
            this.field[i][k] = new Cell(num)
            num++
        }
        else 
            this.field[i][k] = new Cell(num)
    }
};

// ...

for(let i = 0; i<this.field.length; i++){
    for(let k = 0; k< this.field[i].length; k++){
        this.fielElement.appendChild(this.field[i][k]);
    }
}
```

При выполнении appendChild появляется следующая ошибка

> Failed to execute 'appendChild' on 'Node': parameter 1 is not of type 'Node'.

Подскажите, как ее можно исправить?

Comment: код текстом нужно вставлять...

Comment: поправил, подумал что скринами информативней получится

Comment: @RuslanSSS, скрины как правило **менее** информативны, если дело касается кода.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Первым параметром у [`appendChild`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Node/appendChild) должен быть `Node`, О чем и говорится в ошибке.

В коде же передается экземпляр класса `Cell`, который, очевидно не является элементом.

Вероятнее всего внутри этого экземпляра есть ссылка на html элемент, который и надо добавлять.

Comment: что тут является ссылкой ?))
class Cell{
    constructor(num){
         this.num = num;
         this.element = document.createElement(div);
         this.element.className ='cell'
        this.element.setAttribute('ddd',num)


    }

}

Comment: @RuslanSSS, свойство которому ты присваиваешь элемент. В данном случае `this.element = document.createElement(div);`

Comment: спасибо большое

Comment: Блин парень, ты реально помог, полтора дня ломал голову!!!

Comment: @RuslanSSS, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галочка напротив выбранного ответа).

Comment: Спасибо за отзыв! Голоса от участников с репутацией менее 15 учитываются, но не меняют публично отображаемое значение рейтинга.

Comment: @RuslanSSS, надо на саму галочку нажать :)

Comment: ууупс, сделано =D